# Choose previewed tag?

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign

I asked a question about Xen on Arch Linux. The tag [arch-linux] has potential usefulness, but the issue is primarily Xen. But it seems tags are sorted alphabetically so the question shows as `arch linux - title` rather than `xen - title`. I think the tags should be ordered as the user specifies them, or at least store which is the preview tag somehow.

Comment: People search by tags, rather than tags being considered essential to the question itself

Comment: Where are you referring to seeing tag - title?

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is in the <title /> displayed in the browser.

Comment: The tags are automatically ordered from the most frequently used tag to the least used one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is marked as [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71922/why-is-the-first-tag-sometimes-in-the-title-tag-of-some-questions):

> In order to try and stop the scrapers from being ranked higher on Google, they [Stack Exchange] are working on increasing their SEO. **To this end, the tag listed first on a question (sorted by popularity of the tag) will now appear at the start of the page title.**

Comment: Interesting. This feature-request would still be helpful because the question is about Xen but Arch is more popular, but I understand that we can't assume everybody will pick the best option.

Comment: Where is that meta post marked [status-bydesign]?